# ListBox Value Display in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to bind the observable collection with a ListBox and displaying the data on UI (Windows Phone 8.0).
My Listbox have four textblock for four property,

```
<ListBox  x:Name="allListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtBlockStyleDate}" Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtBlockStyle1}" Text="{Binding TypeOfApproval}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtBlockStyle2}" 
                                           Text="{Binding TypeOfRequest}" />
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtBlockStyle3}" Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                                <TextBlock Height="30"></TextBlock>                                    
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

all the objects in observable collection are showing fine, but when any of the property does not have any value, its text block is still there, and its space is kind of visible, which gives the bad impression over UI.
Can you suggest what should i do, when any property is blank, textblock related to that should not eat any height and next textblock should take space of it.
I am attaching an image, see after testing blank space is visible, coz its property is null, i want to remove this space. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need an `IValueConverter`, basically the idea is you do this:

... insert ...

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

... change ...

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtBlockStyleDate}" Visibility="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Text="{Binding Date}"/>
```

Within your `IValueConverter` implementation, you just see if the property is `null` or empty. If it is you just return `Visibility.Collapsed`

Comment: its working fine for string, can you suggest what should i do for DateTime datatype. its gettting failed when i pass DateTime value.
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
                return Visibility.Visible;

Comment: @Maverick Can you be more specific? What do you mean by it's getting failed?

Comment: when i use the property as string, and checking it in ivalueconverter file, it works fine, but when i pass the datetime property, it does not. how should i check for datetime? here value is of datetime. it gives me invalidcast expection error

Comment: @Maverick try this if (object is string) .... else if (object is DateTime) ... (you get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Visibility converter for this!
If your bound data is text, a StringToVisibilityConverter would be fine.

An example on how to do this can be found here: http://www.smallandmighty.net/blog/using-value-converters-to-change-the-visibility-of-a-control